# What is on the cover of this printing of Ladder of Divine Ascent?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, art

What is that? Is it some well-known Orthodox symbol? I think I can discern a bearded face but that's it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sbc's answer and amazon book preview, I have learned that this art doesn't mean anything in particular.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These books are published by Paulist Press, a Catholic publisher. This is not a Orthodox symbol, but there will be a description of the cover art on the page opposite the Table of Contents page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchnage! We are glad you are here.  When you have a minute, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what we are about.  In particular, make sure to read the section of what constitutes a good answer.  Telling the questioner how to answer his own question doesn't really count as an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering an answer. However, though it does point to where an answer could be found, it doesn't actually *provide* an answer. If you looked up the description that your answer points to (which is possible to do online), and provided the information, this would be a much better answer. Please see: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)